# Difference of positive semi-definite matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, convex-cone

If we have $S$ positive semi-definite matrices $A_1,\dots, A_S$ then what is the largest matrix positive semi definite matrix C such that $A_s -C$ is also psd for all $s=1,\dotsc,S$?

By largest I mean in terms of a suitable norm.

Comment: Imagine these were just numbers and that "positive semi-definite" meant "$\geq 0$"; what would the largest C be?

Comment: @jbowman Because numbers are very special--they are totally ordered--as a bit of counterpoint to that suggestion, let $S=2$ and suppose the matrices are $$\pmatrix{1&0\\0&\epsilon}\quad\pmatrix{\epsilon&0\\0&1}$$ for some $0\le\epsilon\lt 1.$ It helps illustrate the fact that psd does not induce a total order on the symmetric matrices.

Comment: @jbowman Equivalence of psd matrices in terms of numbers would the non-negative part of the real line.  The numbers are naturally ordered there, however, psd matrices are not.